# fast report expression matter take part of string and replace it

Tags: c#, delphi, fastreport

im looking for a code in fast report 4 which take 2 first alphabet of string and if it was 10, write red for me, if it was 11 right blue for me

another example

{IF  started with "ab..." then write "RED" 
IF  started with "dc..." then write "Blue"}

Comment: I do not know exactly what you want, please try to explain accurately.

Comment: i want an expression to show only first 2 alphabet of sting.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
procedure Page1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  if Copy(Memo2.Text,1,2) = 'ab' then
  begin
    Memo2.Text:= 'Red';                                                        
    Memo2.Font.Color:= clRed;  
  end;  

  if Copy(Memo6.Text,1,2) = 'dc' then
  begin
    Memo6.Text:= 'Blue';                                                                      
    Memo6.Font.Color:= clBlue;
  end;        
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
Var Str : String;
begin
Str := 'Your String';
Str := Copy (Str , 1 , 2 );
If Str='Yo' then
 ShowMessage('RED')
  else
      If Str='You' then
         ShowMessage('BLUE');
```